# How to add in GridView table sign money?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

I have the query and the output.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="Grid1" runat="server" CssClass="table table-condensed" AllowSorting="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="20" GridLines="None" DataSourceID="MSQLData" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Grid1_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="MSQLData" runat="server"
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MySQLString %>"
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MySQLString.ProviderName %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT c.clinic_name AS `Название`,a.analyze_name AS `Анализ`,a.analyze_price AS `Стоимость` FROM analyzes a JOIN clinics c ON a.clinic_id=c.id ORDER BY a.analyze_name,a.analyze_price"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

everything works goood ! Only, How to add, in column with name a.analyze_price sign $.

like this for examle:

```
|Стоимость|
| 520.3 $ |
```

Now I have this:

```
 |Стоимость|
 | 520.3   |
```

analyze_price - On Sql base with type double.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can concat it at query level
Use char instead of nvarchar

```
SELECT c.clinic_name AS `Название`,a.analyze_name AS `Анализ`,
concat(cast(a.analyze_price as char(100)),'',' $') AS `Стоимость` 
FROM analyzes a JOIN clinics c ON a.clinic_id=c.id ORDER BY a.analyze_name,a.analyze_price
```

Comment: Not work. Error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'nvarchar(50))+' $' AS `Стоимость` FROM analyzes a JOIN clinics c ON a.c' at line 1"}

Comment: Thanks for help. Now not error,but not added sign to column

Comment: hi just my mistake , add `$` this sign at end of `concat('','',' $') ` try to add this at the end

Answer (score 3):

Did you try using `DataFormatString="{0:C}"` on your column?

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="SomeValue" DataFormatString="{0:C}" />
```

It will display the currency symbol according to the locale settings. But for this you need to use `bound fields`.

### Edit-1

You will have to remove auto-generate columns and use bound fileds.

Comment: If I want to add not $? For examle russian ruble?

Comment: @Shato-UmarDaltsaev Here is are [more formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Sorry! Don`t understant where there russian ruble?

Comment: Have you done culture setting for you page or project

Answer (score 1):

How about using [`"C"` (or currency) standard numeric format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#CFormatString) in [`DataFormatString` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of your column like;

```
DataFormatString = "{0:C}"
```

This format represents your value with your [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)'s [`CurrencySymbol` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencysymbol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).